# What's the essential difference between grep foo $(CMD) and CMD | grep foo

Tags: bash, command-line

It's really important because intuitively they are all similar for me.

Could one realise that those two are really like one another for me, i.e. absolutely equal?

Comment: I can't say why I don't understand.

Comment: did you mean `grep SMTH <(CMD)` instead of `grep SMTH $(CMD)`? cause first one is really close to `CMD | grep SMTH`.

Comment: This is not a bad question, I would upvote it if only you please stopped spamming your own questions with so much confusion and - is it anger? Relax! You won't learn anything as all your energy will be wasted on being constantly on fire.

Comment: sorry, you were right. `xi@localhost ~ $ grep SRC_URI $(find /usr/portage -name *.ebuild) | wc -l
25921
xi@localhost ~ $ cat $(find /usr/portage -name *.ebuild) | grep SRC_URI | wc -l
25921
` - no difference, except for inclusion of filename with direct `grep`

Answer (score 8):

They don't do the same thing at all. The former is command substitution, the latter is piping. The result is completely different.

`grep foo "$(echo foo)"` will look for the word "foo" in a file called "foo", because "foo" is the output from `echo`. `echo foo | grep foo` will look for the word "foo" from its `STDIN` input. In the former case, you'll probably get a file not found error. In the latter case, you won't. They're fundamentally not the same operation.

Comment: It might be simply didn't fit my mind cause I used to know there are 3 working principles: STDIN STDOUT STDERR. From your perspective I couldn't use pipe with any given command that I want to use. Because I must somehow know with what command work - 3 cases, or even more - with 4th case - with file. Surely I have mess in my head. I'm very unsure that help (man page) consist of such things as arguments. Are those - arguments, or I'm bad at terminology?

Comment: The standard streams are not arguments, they are streams provided to the program.

Comment: Next moment, now It seems that I can't use $() because it is not at least as good in description as pipe (takes something from STDIN(OUT))

Comment: equery -q uses `equery -q files '*'` bash: /usr/bin/equery: Argument list too long              equery -q uses `xargs equery -q files '*'`

Comment: xargs equery -q uses `equery -q files '*'`

Comment: Nothing works. The essential difference of "this is pipe and this is substitution. because(grep explanation). so not the same" - is not caught, simply because of no contents of such a help:

Comment: equery -q files '*' | xargs equery uses
!!! Invalid atom: 'query.py: find_best(), bestmatch-visible, query=/usr, InvalidAtom=/usr'
!!! Invalid atom: 'query.py: find_best(), bestmatch-visible, query=/usr/lib32/libdrm_nouveau.so.1, InvalidAtom=/usr/lib32/libdrm_nouveau.so.1'
!!! Invalid atom: 'query.py: find_best(), bestmatch-visible, query=/usr/share/screen/utf8encodings/c6, InvalidAtom=/usr/share/screen/utf8encodings/c6'

Comment: @Xsi Sorry, I don't at all understand what you are saying.

Comment: echo "X acl acpi alsa amd64 anthy bzip2 cairo cjk cli consolekit crypt cxx fbcon fortran gif gpm gtk immqt-bc jpeg m17n-lib mmx modules mp3 mp4 mpeg multilib ncurses nls nptl ogg opengl openmp pcre pdf png policykit readline scim sdl sse sse2 ssl symlink tiff truetype udev unicode usb xcb xml xvid zlib" > $(wc -l)

Comment: Don't work. Dont understand - dont post

Comment: emerge -p $(equery -q b --name-only --full-regex '^/usr/bin/g?vim.*')

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:
Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] app-editors/vim-core-7.3.409 
[ebuild   R    ] app-editors/vim-7.3.409

Comment: emerge -p $(equery -q b --full-regex --early-out --name-only '^/usr/bin/g?vim.*')
These are the packages that would be merged, in order:
Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] app-editors/vim-7.3.409

Comment: The output of the last command differs. Might it be that it because of cycle?

Comment: I have no idea what you are saying, sorry. The problem isn't with your question, it's that I can't understand your English (sorry!)